# How to efficiently serialize map to json string when map changed slightly multiple times

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have a map with typically 100 (key, value) pairs and I can use library like Gson or Jackson to serialize it to json string.
Then I need to add one  pair in the map and serialize the updated map again.
With the method I know, the 2nd serialization need to traverse the map again while 99% part is same as the 1st.
Is there a efficient way I can save the work from first serialization and use it in second.

one workaround I have in mind is saving first json string in a string builder, insert (k,v) before the end curly bracket. But it is tricky and error-prone.

Comment: If it is a just a (key, value) map, and you require a more efficient way to update the information, would you consider something like a property file or a CSV? In this way the update would be to simply append a line to the old text. After all the receiver, will need to deserialize, that is parse from the whole document, anyway.

Comment: @user2688838, thanks for your comment. json is message format between system which cannot be changed.